# Is there a way to generate a test folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I'm pretty new to rails and I created a rails application and deleted my test folder to save space. Now that I want to learn TDD, I want to know if there is a way to generate the test folders. To put simply, a reverse of -T.

```
rails new [name] -T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `rails g ...` in another folder, and move the test folder over. There's very little in the default tests, so there's no point in making a custom generator for them.

BTW congratulations on deciding to TDD. Minutes of TDD will save you hours of debugging.